# How to make working security cameras?

Tags: camera, video

I am rendering a cctv room where theres a camera looking at an object and output its view on a screen

Heres a simple setup as a quick visualization.
[image: Set up]

The Camera on the right sees the cube and output it on the black screen where the left camera is looking at. How can i achieve this?

Comment: It is not possible to do that directly. You can  you can do this by compositing. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67714/use-the-view-from-other-cameras-in-the-scene-as-videotexture-in-cycles. and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/48132/how-can-i-view-the-camera-through-an-object-as-a-material-in-cycles/48275#48275 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/111632/workflow-for-multi-subject-multi-angle-compositions/111635#111635  Somehow related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/21738/infinite-tunnel-droste-effect

Comment: What you can do is make the screen you want to project onto the material with the surface being the render result.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know how to automate this but you could render from the cctv’s perspective into a texture and use that as an input into an emission shader for the monitor.

Unless blender can expand and update images sequences during animation rendering then animating this would be much more difficult and this solution dissolves with multiple cctv cameras.